# Best way to periodically execute a PHP script?

Tags: php, cron

I'd probably figure out a way to do this if I had full access to the server, however the problem is it's just a hosting service which leaves me with nothing but **FTP access**.

I would like to run a PHP script periodically to check for outdated/broken content, aggregate new content, delete files not in use etc, however the script can take **up to 60 seconds** to execute (due to aggregation of content) and I feel like an ass to just execute it while processing a request of the first user that visits the website an hour after it's been updated :P

*Leaving my home PC on 24/7 to schedule requests is not an option.*

Comment: Google for `webcron`, lots of services offering this.

Comment: If running the script via HTTP, be mindful of execution timeouts. While you can use `set_time_limit()` to let PHP run the script longer than usual, some web servers (Apache) have their own process time limits in place that you cannot change. Ask your host if they'll let you set up a cron script

Comment: You could, theoretically, circumvent the hard time limit of some webhosts by relying on two visits. Basically, use my approach, then redirect the user a *second* time, running the second part of your long script. Splitting the execution time by half, and redirecting the user two times. Yes, poor user. Haha.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an online cron service to essentially pretend like you have cron access.

Create php file with contents you would like executed

[Free Cron Online Website](http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/)

Set up your free online cron to execute that file every x minutes.

Comment: Wow, that's an awesome site. This will definitely get me started!

Comment: Yep, great site, bookmarked. Thanks for telling us about it :)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the correct approach, but I used to just trigger a script when the first user visits the site, and then send a `<meta http-equiv="refresh"...` to the user for his browser to refresh the page. The original PHP script would still run on the server, but the user will not see it anymore.

Basically, something like:

```
if( check if the user is the first visitor today ) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=..." />"; // put your site baseurl in here

    ... run your scripts here
}
```

Just an idea. Might not work. Just try it out.

Comment: Hey, that sounds like a good idea. I assume redirecting the user using Header("Location: .."); would work as well (continue the script even though it's redirected the user)? I'll try this method ASAP.

Comment: Yes, using a header would be okay, too. Actually, send the header first, and then the meta tag (after that or you'll get an error), so you make sure the user is redirected. Some browsers might ignore the header(Location) for some reason, so the meta tag will ensure the redirect. Just a habit of mine. Hope this works for you! :)

Comment: Ok, great stuff! Will try both methods and see which works out best for me :) Thanks

Comment: If you do it this way, then the first visitor of the day may receive stale data. In some situations, this may be acceptable, but I don't think it's a very good solution.

Comment: Well, it might be acceptable. Or use web-based cronjobs. Maybe, you could even display a message like "Website updating, data displayed might be outdated" while the cron/php script is running, then remove it as soon as its done. Sometimes, you'll just have to find a workaround.

Comment: Well, I do really appreciate your answer and it's a nice and creative workaround, so thanks for that :) but I'm gonna mark Blake as the accepted answer, it seems like a more proper and stable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do without cron using the following solution (PHP only): [How to run PHP cron tasks without cron available](http://a32.me/2012/01/do-php-cron-without-cron-available)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
crontab
```

Take a look here:

[Cron wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: The OP specifically said that there is no other access on the server except FTP.

Comment: And if a hosting is providing only FTP access. Will they allow a script to execute for more than 60 seconds?

Comment: @ntenisOT Strangely, i've been able to run scripts with execution times of over 2 minutes, actually :P

Comment: That's really strange mate. crontab is the easiest way to do that. You can use a different server that you own to set a crontab there..

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting provider doesn't give you anything but FTP access, *and* you don't want to schedule a periodic request from another machine, then there's nothing you can do. You'll have to get a better hosting account, preferably one that lets you use cron.

Comment: Rely on a client/visitor to do that, then shift the client out. See my method above. :)