# Online service that loads my PHP script repeatedly?

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks, intervals

I don't have access to the PHP bundle, I just want to register somewhere my script, than run it every hour. Any possibility?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853057/best-way-to-periodically-execute-a-php-script

Comment: All such services are listed at http://www.onlinecronservices.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.mywebcron.com seems the best. Has no interval limitations.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the shell, you could setup a [CRON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job.

```
5 * * * * php your_script_here.php
```

Comment: I do not, unfortuneatly, I've heard about CRON before.