# how do I run php code without users visiting the page?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, continuous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to periodically execute a PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853057/best-way-to-periodically-execute-a-php-script)

I need to run a php script which continuously collects information from one site, and as soon as that information is collected I need the server to store the information on the database and then update other sites and to continuously repeat the process. The only problem is that I need these php scripts to run without the user visiting the page or even the site for that matter.

Not only this I need the scripts to be running 24/7 or at least run when one site has changed, enabling it to update the others almost instantly. Can anyone suggest what I can do?

Comment: Have the script reside as daemon or run it periodically with cron. Though for least trouble with (possible) memory leaks I suggest you run it with cron every minute and use a locker file to prevent multiple processes in case previous launch hasn't finished its job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have your PHP script run as a [**cron**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job.

*(Of course, you'll need to be able to set up cron jobs on your server)*

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not sure if i'll be able to edit the server as I'll be using a remote hosting service :( is there anyway of using this without editing the server, or is there another work around?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for Cron Jobs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Many hosting providers have an interface that lets you set up jobs. If your provider uses CPanel, then see this page: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Cron+Jobs

If on Windows, then use Scheduled Tasks.

Comment: Broken link? I couldn't acess it

Comment: @gota: Fixed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to create daemon using PHP.

Have a look at this http://devlog.info/2010/03/07/creating-daemons-in-php/

Comment: Handy for some situations but this wont run the script without the user first activating the page by visiting it.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Maybe we can have admin page or something like that.