# PHP perform action every X minutes

Tags: php, api

I've made a PHP script that gets tweets from twitter and saves them to a file for use (as JSON).
Problem is that I only get the tweets once when I execute the script, but I want to get it about every 4-5 minutes.

I've looked into `sleep` but that just delays the browser and executes the action once.
I want to be executed **every** 4 minutes, not just once after a delay.

I looked into cron aswell but the server that I'm going to run my application on does not allow me to use cron.

TL;DR: Anybody know a good way to execute a php script every X minutes after the first execution?

Comment: some kind of cron is the only practical solution for something like this.

Comment: You have no choice but to use cron or something similar here. PHP itself has nothing to offer.

Comment: No crons on a server is a deal breaker. PHP needs crons.

Comment: Then run cron on a local machine and make it call your live server :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to periodically execute a PHP script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853057/best-way-to-periodically-execute-a-php-script)

Answer (score 2):

The best bet for this would be to schedule a task to call your PHP page every x mins rather than trying to keep a thread open. Take a look at a [CRON JOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

The scheduled task doesn't need to be executed from the server if you make the page publically accessible.

Comment: Please read my question again:"I looked into cron aswell but the server that I'm going to run my application on does not allow me to use cron."

Comment: I should have added the CRON job doesn't need to be on that server. You could just expose it and call it from any where. Even set up a schedule job on your local PC to execute your browser with the address passed in as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a web monitoring service (some are free, like Pingdom) to make a HTTP request your page every X minutes, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There are providers that offer nothing but running cron jobs for you. Look into them, they could just call your php script every x minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you do to make this work without cron is a hack.

You *could* go

```
while (1) {
  process(...)
  sleep(4*60)
}
```

But you'll run into problems with PHPs execution time limits.

Maybe it's an option to have your script do the action once, and have it called from a cron-capable host every 4 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the question myself.
As stated in my question, Javascript and Jquery are also viable solutions.
I used a `setInterval` to perform a $.get on my twitter.php file every X minutes.

Comment: But you'll need to keep this browser window open the whole time. With a cron you can have it running in the background with no visible UI.

Comment: @DaveHogan Which is not a viable solution, since I cannot use cron, regardless of how well it works.

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't use cron. You host doesn't allow it, that's fine and I understand. What I'm trying to say in my answer is that you can use another PC anywhere in the world to access your page at a defined period.

Comment: I never stated that your solution was wrong. The difference between my solution and yours is that I know how to make mine, while wikipedia doesn't explain anything except how to write the code.

Comment: That's a different question then