# How do I run PHP code every 1 minute?

Tags: php

I have got this php code

```
$uploaded=0;
$_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame']=$uploaded;
if (isset($_POST['UploadMSub'])) {
    $uploaded++;
    $_SESSION['firstUploadTime'] = time();
}


function isFileUploadAllowed() {
    $isAllowed                  = true;
    $timeNow                    = time();
    $timeFrameInSeconds         = 30;
    $maxUploadsInTimeFrame      = 5;
    $firstUploadTime            = $_SESSION['firstUploadTime'] ? intval($_SESSION['firstUploadTime']) : $timeNow;
    $numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame = $_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame'] ? intval($_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame']) : 0;
    $givenTimeFrameExpired      = (($firstUploadTime + $timeFrameInSeconds) < $timeNow);
    if (!$givenTimeFrameExpired) {
        if ($numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame + 1 > $maxUploadsInTimeFrame) {
            $isAllowed = false;
        }
    }

    if ($isAllowed === true) {
        if ($givenTimeFrameExpired) {
            $_SESSION['firstUploadTime'] = $timeNow;
            $_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame'] = 0;
        }

        $_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame']++;
    }
    return $isAllowed;
}
```

How can i make that so every 60 seconds $_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame'] will be decreased by one
Please do not suggest sleep() or Cron

Comment: You can store all upload times than count the ones that are inside your timeframe.

Comment: From the command line, or from the browser?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think browser will be more comfortable

Comment: I did not understand you @RolandStarke

Comment: you can send ajax requests to your php page

Comment: If you want to run from your browser you would use a [meta-refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)

Comment: There is no need to run your script each min. You could just calculate the time difference between 2 calls.

Comment: Well it will calculate the difference only once,won't it?@RolandStarke

Comment: @JayBlanchard actually i think kamal pal's suggestions was the easiest now i am trying to do that

Comment: @kamalpal What about posting code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to echo something every 4 minutes while in an endless loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877692/how-to-echo-something-every-4-minutes-while-in-an-endless-loop) or [PHP perform action every X minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427760/php-perform-action-every-x-minutes)

Comment: I have tried that and it is not working @AniMenon please delete that

Comment: Why isn't it working? Post the error.

Comment: @AniMenon Max time of execution 30 seconds

Comment: @TomOdell There are multiple solutions given in those links like cronjob, setinterval, while-loop, etc.

Comment: @AniMenon there 2 solutions and none of them was accepted by asker and none is satisfying for me

Comment: @TomOdell good luck finding a different solution then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), inside `setInterval` of 60000 ms = 1 min , see example below:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url to your php script you want to execute',
        method: 'post',
        aysnc: false,
        data: {
            var: 'value'
        }
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}, 60000);
```

Comment: What about php?What should i write there?

Comment: you can write php script, which you want to execute every min

Comment: But how do i check if this request was sent?There is not "data" here

Comment: you can check on browser console, it will output what it receives from php script, additionally you can write logs in your php script to debug process.

Comment: I mean how php script will know if this request was sent

Comment: you have to provide url to your php script, in ajax call .. it will be executed, see I've left placeholder for url in example

Comment: I know but should i just posts  $_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame']-- without any ifs?

Comment: you don't need to post session, php script can access that, but if you want to send any additional data, you can send it .. see my updated answer